# Adding Rich Text Box or WordPad like textbox in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I'm having trouble with my excel vba. I want to add a textbox where I can underline, highlight, or manipulate the text. Is that possible?

Here's the scenario: the textbox in a Userform will pull out the information from columns in excel. Once the information is shown in the textbox, a user can annotate, underline, or highlight a specific word and save it. So, this means, there's a need for a word-like textbox.

How can this be resolved? Hope you could help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible ryemus sry!
RichText Bow has been disabled since Excel 2003 and wasn't that useful anyway...

For what you need, I'm not sure that VBA will be enough... Maybe with checkboxes to underline data in excel or that kind of things